# Trouble running node to test Web3

Tags: web3js, testrpc

I'm trying to test basic web3 with node. I have testrpc running and I have the following in a javascript file:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
```

When I run `node filename.js` it returns undefined. Why is that?

When I change `web3.eth.accounts[0]` to `web3.eth.accounts` I get this :

```
Accounts {
currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
_requestManager:
 RequestManager {
 provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
 providers:
  { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
    HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
    IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
 subscriptions: {} },
givenProvider: null,
providers:
{ WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
 HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
 IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
_provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
setProvider: [Function],
_ethereumCall:
{ getId:
  { [Function: send]
    method: [Object],
    request: [Function: bound ],
    call: 'net_version' },
 getGasPrice:
  { [Function: send]
    method: [Object],
    request: [Function: bound ],
    call: 'eth_gasPrice' },
 getTransactionCount:
  { [Function: send]
    method: [Object],
    request: [Function: bound ],
    call: 'eth_getTransactionCount' } },
wallet:
Wallet {
 _accounts: [Circular],
 length: 0,
 defaultKeyName: 'web3js_wallet' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the async call work?

```
web3.eth.getAccounts((error, result) => {
  if (result && result.length > 0) {
    console.log(result[0]);
  }
  else {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
  }
}
```

Also be sure to double check that you didn't start testrpc on another port and that it's up and listening (I've had the process die on me more than once without noticing).

Comment: I actually just ran your code snippet and it worked. Do you know why I can't run it regularly?

Comment: @JorahFriendzone Are you using web3 v1.0 beta? That version only supports async calls, ie callbacks or promievents.

Comment: @Ismael Yeah that was the problem, I was on v1.0 beta. Thanks!